# Google Adsense ad doesn't appear

Tags: python, html, flask, adsense

I have problem about Adsense ad, when I click on my page source code, the ad script is here, but ad doesn't appear, see below in link.

Ad could appear on top of the topic.

Link to the page:
http://improveyourself.sk/article_2

UPDATE:
my script code:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <!-- Test ad -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-5699588432146886"
         data-ad-slot="8670387053"></ins>
    <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script should like this:

```
<script  src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
 style="display:block"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxx"
 data-ad-slot="xxxx"
 data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Change your first script address. use show_ads.js instead of adsbygoogle.js.

Answer (score 0):

The ad is in fact loaded but the space collapsed. This is mainly caused by AdSense not being able to detect the available space for the ad.

Here is an artikel that helps your problem.

https://webgilde.com/en/adsense-auto-resizing-error/